# sencha architect, webBuild: Architect does not have Cmd installed

Tags: extjs

I uninstalled Sencha Architect 3.1 and installed 3.2, then have the issue with the running a build on the project.

```
 webBuild: Architect does not have Cmd installed.
```

So I uninstalled 3.2 and re-installed 3.1, the issue is still there.
My box is win 8, jdk 7, ruby 1.9 , ant 1.9.3. Below is my platform.

```
  version:3.1.0.1943
  channel:3.1-stable
  platform:1.4.1.960
  cmd:5.0.2.270
  framework:Ext JS 5.0.x
```

In my Project settings, it says "Not Installed" next to Build Tools. "sendcha", "java", "ant" can run from command line.So PATH enviroment has no problem.

Could someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to install Cmd in addition to Architect?

Comment: I installed Cmd just now. It does not work.

Comment: Hmm, so it is not that simple as I thought. Consider contacting Sencha support.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? Having the same here...

Answer (score 0):

Before you reinstall 3.1, you have to delete

*C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Sencha\Sencha Architect 3.2*.